# Cannot find centroid of path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, chart.js, usmap

I have an issue with d3.js.
I cannot understand how to work with some functions.
I need help. 
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tooltip"></div><!-- div to hold tooltip. -->
<!--<svg width="960" height="600" id="statesvg"></svg> &lt;!&ndash; svg to hold the map. &ndash;&gt;-->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="uStates.js"></script> <!-- creates uStates. -->
<input type="file" id="fileUpload"  onchange="a.parseExcel(event) "/>
<hr />
<div id="dvExcel"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/jszip.js"></script>
<script>
    const ExcelToJSON = function() {

        this.parseExcel = function(file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                const data = e.target.result;
                const workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                    type: 'binary'
                });
                workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                    // Here is your object
                    if(sheetName === 'Data')
                    {
                        const XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                        const json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
                        const data = json_object;
                        if (data) {
                            drawMap(data);
                        }
                    }
                })

            };

            reader.onerror = function(ex) {
                console.log(ex);
            };

            reader.readAsBinaryString(file.target.files[0]);
        };
    };
    function tooltipHtml(n, d){ /* function to create html content string in tooltip div. */
        return "<h4>"+n+"</h4><table>"+
            "<tr><td>Low</td><td>"+(d[25])+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>Average</td><td>"+(d.avg)+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>High</td><td>"+(d.high)+"</td></tr>"+
            "</table>";
    }
    let a = new ExcelToJSON();
    const states = {
        "AL": "Alabama",
        "AK": "Alaska",
        "AS": "American Samoa",
        "AZ": "Arizona",
        "AR": "Arkansas",
        "CA": "California",
        "CO": "Colorado",
        "CT": "Connecticut",
        "DE": "Delaware",
        ...............
    };
    var sampleData ={}; /* Sample random data. */
    function drawMap(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        ["HI", "AK", "FL", "SC", "GA", "AL", "NC", "TN", "RI", "CT", "MA",
            "ME", "NH", "VT", "NY", "NJ", "PA", "DE", "MD", "WV", "KY", "OH",
            "MI", "WY", "MT", "ID", "WA", "DC", "TX", "CA", "AZ", "NV", "UT",
            "CO", "NM", "OR", "ND", "SD", "NE", "IA", "MS", "IN", "IL", "MN",
            "WI", "MO", "AR", "OK", "KS", "LS", "VA"]
            .forEach(function(d){
                let newData;
                newData = data.filter(item => {
                    return item["Age of Retirement"].trim().toUpperCase() === states[d].trim().toUpperCase();
                });
                const stateData = newData[0];
                sampleData[d] = {};
                for (let key in stateData) {
                    if (!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
                        console.log(key);
                        sampleData[d][key] = stateData[key];
                        let a = stateData[25].replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                        sampleData[d].color = d3.interpolate("#ffffff", "#77062e")(parseInt(a)/10000000);
                    }
                }
            });
        console.log(sampleData);

        /* draw states on id #statesvg */
        uStates.draw("#statesvg", sampleData, tooltipHtml);

        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "600px");
    }



</script>

</body>
```

uStates.js

```
(function(){
    var uStatePaths=[
        {id:"HI",n:"Hawaii",d:"M233.08751,519.30948L235.02744,515.75293L237.2907,515.42961L237.61402,516.23791L235.51242,519.30948L233.08751,519.30948ZM243.27217,515.59127L249.4153,518.17784L251.51689,517.85452L253.1335,513.97465L252.48686,510.57977L248.28366,510.09479L244.24213,511.87306L243.27217,515.59127ZM273.9878,525.61427L277.706,531.11074L280.13092,530.78742L281.26255,530.30244L282.7175,531.59573L286.43571,531.43407L287.40568,529.97912L284.49577,528.20085L282.55584,524.48263L280.45424,520.92609L274.63444,523.83599L273.9878,525.61427ZM294.19545,534.50564L295.48874,532.5657L300.17691,533.53566L300.82356,533.05068L306.96668,533.69732L306.64336,534.99062L304.05678,536.44556L299.69193,536.12224L294.19545,534.50564ZM299.53027,539.67879L301.47021,543.55866L304.54176,542.42703L304.86509,540.81041L303.24848,538.70882L299.53027,538.3855L299.53027,539.67879ZM306.4817,538.54716L308.74496,535.63726L313.43313,538.06218L317.79798,539.19381L322.16284,541.94205L322.16284,543.88198L318.6063,545.66026L313.75645,546.63022L311.33154,545.17527L306.4817,538.54716ZM323.13281,554.06663L324.74942,552.77335L328.14431,554.38997L335.74238,557.94651L339.13727,560.0481L340.75387,562.47302L342.69381,566.83787L346.73534,569.42445L346.41202,570.71775L342.53215,573.95097L338.32896,575.40592L336.87401,574.75928L333.80244,576.53754L331.37753,579.77077L329.11427,582.68067L327.33599,582.51901L323.77945,579.93243L323.45613,575.40592L324.10277,572.981L322.48616,567.32286L320.38456,565.54458L320.2229,562.958L322.48616,561.98804L324.58776,558.91648L325.07274,557.94651L323.45613,556.16823L323.13281,554.06663Z"},
        {id:"AK",n:"Alaska",d:"M158.07671,453.67502L157.75339,539.03215L159.36999,540.00211L162.44156,540.16377L163.8965,539.03215L166.48308,539.03215L166.64475,541.94205L173.59618,548.73182L174.08117,551.3184L177.47605,549.37846L178.1227,549.2168L178.44602,546.14524L179.90096,544.52863L181.0326,544.36697L182.97253,542.91201L186.04409,545.01361L186.69074,547.92352L188.63067,549.05514L189.7623,551.48006L193.64218,553.25833L197.03706,559.2398L199.78529,563.11966L202.04855,565.86791L203.50351,569.58611L208.515,571.36439L213.68817,573.46598L214.65813,577.83084L215.14311,580.9024L214.17315,584.29729L212.39487,586.56054L210.77826,585.75224L209.32331,582.68067L206.57507,581.22573L204.7968,580.09409L203.98849,580.9024L205.44344,583.65065L205.6051,587.36885L204.47347,587.85383L202.53354,585.9139L200.43195,584.62061L200.91693,586.23722L202.21021,588.0155L201.40191,588.8238C201.40191,588.8238,200.59361,588.50048,200.10863,587.85383C199.62363,587.20719,198.00703,584.45895,198.00703,584.45895L197.03706,582.19569C197.03706,582.19569,196.71374,583.48898,196.06709,583.16565C195.42044,582.84233,194.7738,581.71071,194.7738,581.71071L196.55207,579.77077L195.09712,578.31582L195.09712,573.30432L194.28882,573.30432L193.48052,576.6992L192.34888,577.1842L191.37892,573.46598L190.73227,569.74777L189.92396,569.26279L190.24729,574.92094L190.24729,576.05256L188.79233,574.75928L185.23579,568.77781L183.13419,568.29283L182.48755,564.57462L180.87094,561.66472L179.25432,560.53308L179.25432,558.26983L181.35592,556.97654L180.87094,556.65322L178.28436,557.29986L174.88947,554.87495L172.30289,551.96504L167.45306,549.37846L163.41152,546.79188L164.70482,543.55866L164.70482,541.94205L162.92654,543.55866L160.01664,544.69029L156.29843,543.55866L150.64028,541.13375L145.14381,541.13375L144.49717,541.61873L138.03072,537.73885L135.92912,537.41553L133.18088,531.59573L129.62433,531.91905L126.06778,533.374L126.55277,537.90052L127.68439,534.99062L128.65437,535.31394L127.19941,539.67879L130.43263,536.93055L131.07928,538.54716L127.19941,542.91201L125.90612,542.58869L125.42114,540.64875L124.12785,539.84045L122.83456,540.97208L120.08632,539.19381L117.01475,541.29541L115.23649,543.397L111.8416,545.4986L107.15342,545.33693L106.66844,543.23534L110.38664,542.58869L110.38664,541.29541L108.12338,540.64875L109.09336,538.22384L111.35661,534.34397L111.35661,532.5657L111.51827,531.75739L115.88313,529.49413L116.85309,530.78742L119.60134,530.78742L118.30805,528.20085L114.58983,527.87752L109.57834,530.62576L107.15342,534.02064L105.37515,536.60723L104.24352,538.87049L100.04033,540.32543L96.96876,542.91201L96.645439,544.52863L98.908696,545.4986L99.717009,547.60018L96.96876,550.83341L90.502321,555.03661L82.742574,559.2398L80.640977,560.37142L75.306159,561.50306L69.971333,563.76631L71.749608,565.0596L70.294654,566.51455L69.809672,567.64618L67.061434,566.67621L63.828214,566.83787L63.019902,569.10113L62.049939,569.10113L62.37326,566.67621L58.816709,567.96951L55.90681,568.93947L52.511924,567.64618L49.602023,569.58611L46.368799,569.58611L44.267202,570.87941L42.65059,571.68771L40.548995,571.36439L37.962415,570.23276L35.699158,570.87941L34.729191,571.84937L33.112578,570.71775L33.112578,568.77781L36.184142,567.48452L42.488929,568.13117L46.853782,566.51455L48.955378,564.41296L51.86528,563.76631L53.643553,562.958L56.391794,563.11966L58.008406,564.41296L58.978369,564.08964L61.241626,561.3414L64.313196,560.37142L67.708076,559.72478L69.00137,559.40146L69.648012,559.88644L70.456324,559.88644L71.749608,556.16823L75.791141,554.71329L77.731077,550.99508L79.994336,546.46856L81.610951,545.01361L81.934272,542.42703L80.317657,543.72032L76.922764,544.36697L76.276122,541.94205L74.982838,541.61873L74.012865,542.58869L73.851205,545.4986L72.39625,545.33693L70.941306,539.51713L69.648012,540.81041L68.516388,540.32543L68.193068,538.3855L64.151535,538.54716L62.049939,539.67879L59.463361,539.35547L60.918305,537.90052L61.403286,535.31394L60.756645,533.374L62.211599,532.40404L63.504883,532.24238L62.858241,530.4641L62.858241,526.09925L61.888278,525.12928L61.079966,526.58423L54.936843,526.58423L53.481892,525.29094L52.835247,521.41108L50.733651,517.85452L50.733651,516.88456L52.835247,516.07625L52.996908,513.97465L54.128536,512.84303L53.320231,512.35805L52.026941,512.84303L50.895313,510.09479L51.86528,505.08328L56.391794,501.85007L58.978369,500.23345L60.918305,496.51525L63.666554,495.22195L66.253132,496.35359L66.576453,498.77851L69.00137,498.45517L72.23459,496.03026L73.851205,496.67691L74.821167,497.32355L76.437782,497.32355L78.701041,496.03026L79.509354,491.6654C79.509354,491.6654,79.832675,488.75551,80.479317,488.27052C81.125959,487.78554,81.44928,487.30056,81.44928,487.30056L80.317657,485.36062L77.731077,486.16893L74.497847,486.97723L72.557911,486.49225L69.00137,484.71397L63.989875,484.55231L60.433324,480.83411L60.918305,476.95424L61.564957,474.52932L59.463361,472.75105L57.523423,469.03283L58.008406,468.22453L64.798177,467.73955L66.899773,467.73955L67.869736,468.70951L68.516388,468.70951L68.354728,467.0929L72.23459,466.44626L74.821167,466.76958L76.276122,467.90121L74.821167,470.00281L74.336186,471.45775L77.084435,473.07437L82.095932,474.85264L83.874208,473.88268L81.610951,469.51783L80.640977,466.2846L81.610951,465.47629L78.21606,463.53636L77.731077,462.40472L78.21606,460.78812L77.407756,456.90825L74.497847,452.22007L72.072929,448.01688L74.982838,446.07694L78.21606,446.07694L79.994336,446.72359L84.197528,446.56193L87.915733,443.00539L89.047366,439.93382L92.765578,437.5089L94.382182,438.47887L97.130421,437.83222L100.84863,435.73062L101.98027,435.56896L102.95023,436.37728L107.47674,436.21561L110.22498,433.14405L111.35661,433.14405L114.91316,435.56896L116.85309,437.67056L116.36811,438.80219L117.01475,439.93382L118.63137,438.31721L122.51124,438.64053L122.83456,442.35873L124.7745,443.81369L131.88759,444.46033L138.19238,448.66352L139.64732,447.69356L144.82049,450.28014L146.92208,449.6335L148.86202,448.82518L153.71185,450.76512L158.07671,453.67502ZM42.973913,482.61238L45.075509,487.9472L44.913847,488.91717L42.003945,488.59384L40.225672,484.55231L38.447399,483.09737L36.02248,483.09737L35.86082,480.51078L37.639093,478.08586L38.770722,480.51078L40.225672,481.96573L42.973913,482.61238ZM40.387333,516.07625L44.105542,516.88456L47.823749,517.85452L48.632056,518.8245L47.015444,522.5427L43.94388,522.38104L40.548995,518.8245L40.387333,516.07625ZM19.694697,502.01173L20.826327,504.5983L21.957955,506.21492L20.826327,507.02322L18.72473,503.95166L18.72473,502.01173L19.694697,502.01173ZM5.9534943,575.0826L9.3483796,572.81934L12.743265,571.84937L15.329845,572.17269L15.814828,573.7893L17.754763,574.27429L19.694697,572.33436L19.371375,570.71775L22.119616,570.0711L25.029518,572.65768L23.897889,574.43595L19.533037,575.56758L16.784795,575.0826L13.066588,573.95097L8.7017347,575.40592L7.0851227,575.72924L5.9534943,575.0826ZM54.936843,570.55609L56.553455,572.49602L58.655048,570.87941L57.2001,569.58611L54.936843,570.55609ZM57.846745,573.62764L58.978369,571.36439L61.079966,571.68771L60.271663,573.62764L57.846745,573.62764ZM81.44928,571.68771L82.904234,573.46598L83.874208,572.33436L83.065895,570.39442L81.44928,571.68771ZM90.17899,559.2398L91.310623,565.0596L94.220522,565.86791L99.232017,562.958L103.59687,560.37142L101.98027,557.94651L102.46525,555.52159L100.36365,556.81488L97.453752,556.00657L99.070357,554.87495L101.01029,555.68325L104.89016,553.90497L105.37515,552.45003L102.95023,551.64172L103.75853,549.70178L101.01029,551.64172L96.322118,555.19827L91.472284,558.10817L90.17899,559.2398ZM132.53423,539.35547L134.95915,537.90052L133.98918,536.12224L132.21091,537.09221L132.53423,539.35547Z"},
.......
    ];
    const uStates={};

    const width = 960,
        height = 600;

    const projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
        .scale(700)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    const path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection);

    const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
    uStates.draw = function(id, data, toolTip){
        function mouseOver(d){
            d3.select("#tooltip").transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);

            d3.select("#tooltip").html(toolTip(d.n, data[d.id]))
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        }

        function mouseOut(){
            d3.select("#tooltip").transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);
        }

        svg.selectAll(".state")
            .data(uStatePaths).enter().append("path").attr("class","state").attr("d",function(d){ return d.d;})
            .style("fill",function(d){ return data[d.id].color; })
            .attr("id", function(d){
                return d.id;
            })
            .on("mouseover", mouseOver).on("mouseout", mouseOut);
        svg.selectAll(".stateText")
            .data(uStatePaths)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return path.centroid(d.d)[0];
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                console.log(d, d.d)
                return path.centroid(d.d)[1];
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-size", "12px")
            .text("foo")
    };
    this.uStates=uStates;
    this.asd = uStatePaths;
})();
```

I draw a map in uStates.js file by draw function.
I need to drow labels of each state on theirs.
I find something. But it doesn't work for me.
What do I need to give to centroid function to find the center of the path?

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. Would you mind creating an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a stack snippet? This would help people help you. Most of the code currently shared can be removed, I guess that the relevant part is the rendering of one state's path. Once the centroid for one of these paths can be found, then the same logic can be applied to the other states.

Comment: Please clarify what "But it doesn't work for me" means. Is there an error message in the developer console? Are the positions wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `path.centroid(d)` instead of `path.centroid(d.d)`

Comment: @Mehdi, yes I tried, it's still not working
it returns NaN instead of number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for it.

I created a function getMyCentroid.

```
function getMyCentroid(element) {
        var bbox = element.node().getBBox();
        return [bbox.x + bbox.width/2, bbox.y + bbox.height/2];
    }
```

And call it instead of **centroid** function

```
.attr("x", function(d) {
    return getMyCentroid(d3.select(`#${d.id}`))[0];
})
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return getMyCentroid(d3.select(`#${d.id}`))[1];
})
```

Comment: That's not the centroid though